# How to connect derby database in soapui?

Tags: database, derby, soapui

I am not able to connect derby database from `soapui` though I am able to connect Oracle database.

Can anyone help me out. How to connect derby database in `soapui`?

Comment: Not enough information in your question. What have you tried? What errors are you getting? In any case, here are some things to think about. Do you have the derby drivers? What URL are you supplying? Are you trying to connect to an embedded or a network Derby instance? If network, is the host remote? If it's remote, have you checked the firewall settings? Is the machine reachable over the network? etc...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of supplying the JDBC connection settings:

1. Use a project level JDBC Connection - in this case the driver,
   connection string and password properties will be populated with
   configured values for the selected JDBC Connection (but the fields
   will be disabled and read-only).
2. Use text field values for driver/connection string/password - in
   this case the Database Connection is set to "None".

Answer (score -1):

jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/databasename.db;create=true;user=sa;password=sa

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.